# Is it possible to exploit XSS by replacing image data for img tag

Tags: xss, man-in-the-middle, html

If I have `HTML` page served over `https` with image loaded over `http` (image from other domain):

```
<img src="http://some-image.png"/>
```

so it's possible to inject any data to browser as image by using MITM attack. 
Is it possible to inject some Javascript code instead of image or maybe wrap some code to SVG image to execute this code in browser? Or the only risk is that someone can replace one image with another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do browsers warn about mixed content for images?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17156/why-do-browsers-warn-about-mixed-content-for-images), [Exploiting HTTP content in HTTPS page](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38893).

Answer (score 0):

There're some exploits in old browsers, e.g. Opera10 allows to execute Javascript for SVG fonts in `.svg` files (https://html5sec.org/#43):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg onload="alert(1)" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs><font id="x"><font-face font-family="y"/></font></defs>
</svg>
```